# Markov Inequality for Sum

Tags: probability, random-variable, probability-inequalities

I don't have proper knowledge of probability, I was surfing around internet about Markov's inequality, I found a paper on JSTOR titled "The Markov Inequality for Sums of Independent Random Variables",where something different from usual is given.my question is that, isn't it simply true that for non negative random variables X1,X2,...,Xn:
P(X1+X2+...+Xn≥c) ≤ E(X1+X2+...+Xn)/c.
Please clarify if it is not true in general but under some conditions. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, for any non-negative random variables $X_1,..., X_n$ and any $c>0$ we have:

$$P(X_1+...+X_n \geq c) \leq \frac{E[X_1+...+X_n]}{c}, $$

directly from [Markov's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov%27s_inequality) where we take $X=X_1+...+X_n$.

In their main corollary, for i.i.d non-negative random variables with common expectation $\nu$ and $c\geq \max\{4,n-1\}\cdot n\nu$, the authors refine Markov's inequality:

$$ P(X_1+...+X_n \geq c) \leq 1 - \left(1- \frac{\nu}{c}\right)^n \leq n\frac{\nu}{c}=  \frac{E[X_1+...+X_n]}{c}. $$

Last inequality is an application of [Bernoulli's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli%27s_inequality), noting that $-\frac{\nu}{c}>-1$.

Comment: Thank you. Nicely explained